# React Bootstrap Table has button in each row to create modal, but one button will call modal's render multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table, react-modal

I have a `React Bootstrap Table`, each page of the table has 20 records. In each row, I added a button using following line

```
function attachFormatter(cell, row){
     return (
        <AttachmentManager />
     );
 }
 <TableHeaderColumn key={uuid.v4()}
                   dataField={column.dataField}
                   dataFormat={attachFormatter}
                   hidden={hide}>
                    {column.label}
</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Then I have 20 buttons in this page and each row has one button. I intended to open a modal if click one of the button. But when I click one button, the `openModal()` runs one time as expected, but the `render()` function of my `AttachmentManager` will run 20 times. How to solve this?

```
export default class AttachmentManager extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showModal: false};
    }

    openModal() {
        alert('test');
    }

    render () {
        return (
      <button onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)} className="btn btn-default">Add Projects
        <AttachmentModal show={this.state.showModal}/>
      </button>
        );
    }
}
```

And following is my modal

```
import React from 'react';
import SimpleModal from '../common/SimpleModal';
export default class AttachmentModal extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <SimpleModal showModal={this.props.show}
                       onToggleModal={this.props.onHide}
                       title={this.props.title}
                       onCancelClick={this.props.onHide}
                       onPrimaryButtonClick={this.props.onPrimaryButtonClick}
                       cancelText="Cancel"
                       primaryButtonText={this.props.primaryButtonText}
                       loading={this.props.loading}
                       backdrop='static'
                       bsStyle={this.props.bsStyle}>
                {this.props.children}
            </SimpleModal>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the similar problem and solved it like this.

In attachFormatter, pass the `row` value as props

```
function attachFormatter(cell, row){
     return (
        <AttachmentManager row={row} />
     );
 }
 <TableHeaderColumn key={uuid.v4()}
                   dataField={column.dataField}
                   dataFormat={attachFormatter}
                   hidden={hide}>
                    {column.label}
</TableHeaderColumn>
```

In AttachmentManager, On click of button the set `selectedRow` and `showModal` value.
You can use `isObjectEquivalent` function to compare the row props and selectedRow value.

```
export default class AttachmentManager extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    showModal: false,
    selectedRow: null
   };
  }

  openModal() {
   this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return {
     selectedRow: props.row,
     showModal: true
    }
   });
  }

  isObjectEquivalent(a, b) {
   // Create arrays of property names
   var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
   var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

   // If number of properties is different,
   // objects are not equivalent
   if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
    return false;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
    var propName = aProps[i];

    // If values of same property are not equal,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
     return false;
    }
   }

   // If we made it this far, objects
   // are considered equivalent
   return true;
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
        <button onClick = {this.openModal.bind(this)} className = "btn btn-default"> Add Projects </button> 
        {this.state.showModal && this.isObjectEquivalent(this.props.row, this.state.selectedRow) ? ( < AttachmentModal show = {this.state.showModal} />) : null} 
     </div>
      );
     }
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your component to a PureComponent.

```
export default class AttachmentManager extends React.PureComponent {
...
}
```

Add a key to all your buttons.

```
 <button key={uuid.v4()} onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)} className="btn btn-default">Add Projects
        <AttachmentModal show={this.state.showModal}/>
      </button>
```

Comment: Still same. When I click one button, the `render()` is called 20 times.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `AttachmentModal` to your question?

Comment: See edited code. Even though I deleted the line `<AttachmentModal show={this.state.showModal}/>` in `AttachmentManager` to let the render only create the button, the render still runs multiple times

Comment: Which render method runs 20 times? the `AttachmentModal` or `SimpleModal`?

Comment: render method of `AttachmentManager`